# "With" common table expression

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update, common-table-expression

I have defined common table expression using **DB2** like:

```
With Example_CommonTableExpression AS (select * from Table1 inner join Table2...)
```

I would like to update tableC which has reference in defined CommonTableExpression.

```
update tableC 
  set somefield="xyz" 
where tableC.someValue IN (select someValue 
                           from Example_CommonTableExpression)
```

But I get the following error

> 42601 An unexpected Token "With Example_CommonTableExpression AS (" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT"

Is it like that update does not work with CommonTable Expressions? 
unfortunately I did not find much help in Reference doc [ref doc][1]

**Problem/Workaround:**

I can use the whole select statement  instead of checking it in Example_CommonTableExpression but I have multiple update statements and having a large sub select does not looking appealing.

Comment: Seems like you should create a view instead. A cte doesn't exist after the query has run, while a view can be used over and over again.

Comment: Just in case somebody hasn't memorized all of the error codes for all database systems, can you edit your question to include the text of the error message *and* tag your question with your specific database system.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Sorry just did that.

Comment: If you have many UPDATE statements to reference the same CTE and separate statements are unavoidable by other means, then consider materialising the CTE in an unlogged session table (DGTT) which you can then index dynamically if necessary. You can then reference the session-table (instead of a CTE) in each update statement. Keep in mind you will either need to have all UPDATE statements in one transaction, OR declare the DGTT with on commit preserve rows.

Comment: Multiple statements (`update` or otherwise) cannot reference the same CTE.  The scope of a CTE is limited.  Perhaps you want a view.

Comment: Why do you have multiple `UPDATE` statements? If they are all for the same table, you can update more than one column (and update columns with more than one value) in a single statement.

Comment: @P.Vernon no they are not from same table. as suggested by jarlh i created the view and it works